# move element from a list to another list and inverse javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to move items from the first list in the second and vice versa. First works.
I tried to write for second list,but it doesn't work and i don't know why.
Could someone help me?
This is what i tried to do.

```
   <html>
    <head>
      <script>
      function moveRight() {
    var selItem = document.forms[0].leftList.selectedIndex;
    if (selItem == -1) {
        window.alert("You must first select an item on the left side.")
    } else {
        document.forms[0].rightList.add(document.forms[0].leftList[selItem], null);
    }
}
function moveLeft(){
  var selItem=document.forms[1].leftRight.selectedIndex;
  if (selItem == -1) {
      window.alert("You must first select an item on the right side.")
  } else {
      document.forms[1].leftList.add(document.forms[1].rightList[selItem], null);
  }
}
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <form name="form1" onsubmit="return false;">
    <select name="leftList" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="item1">Item1</option>
      <option value="item2">Item2</option>
      <option value="item3">Item3</option>
      <option value="item4">Item4</option>
    </select>
    <select name="rightList" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="elem1" > Elem1</option>
      <option value="elem2">Elem2</option>
    </select>

    <button onclick="moveRight()">Move to the right</button>
    <button onclick="moveLeft()">Move to the left</button>
</form>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 issues

1: There is no forms[1] element it should be forms[0] only.

2: document.forms[1].leftRight is no elemnt it should be document.forms[0].rightList

```
function moveLeft(){
  var selItem=document.forms[0].rightList.selectedIndex;
  if (selItem == -1) {
      window.alert("You must first select an item on the right side.")
  } else {
      document.forms[0].leftList.add(document.forms[0].rightList[selItem], null);
  }
}
```

Working example: https://plnkr.co/edit/uw28oLtQBjfW9vS0d5ld?p=preview

Comment: Also please note you are only moving one `option` at the time. If you need to move all selected items at the same time use `selectedOptions` instead of `selectedIndex`, that will return a HTMLCollection that you can traverse as an array to move the items.

Comment: On each select add something like `ondblclick="moveRight()"` on the left one and similar on the right one, the select will look like 
`<select name="leftList" multiple="multiple" ondblclick="moveRight()">`

Comment: I want to say to double-click direct on  the item and it moves in the second list and inverse.

Comment: Yes, those changes will do that, check the updated code on https://plnkr.co/edit/XR2DEMNB3ykTm1gQKx8F?p=preview

Comment: It's ok. Thank you :)